# jquery slow remove on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm dynamically populating select fields with a fair amount of option fields fetched by ajax calls, about a thousand ones in the worst case.
Obviously when I populate a select with a new bunch of options I want to remove the old ones.
I noticed that the same operation is almost instantaneous on IE and Chrome but it requires seconds on the last version of Firefox (Firefox 29.0.1).

```
technogym.addCase.serialNumber
.find('option')
.remove()
.end()
.append('<option value=""></option>');
```

Is there a way to make my code faster on firefox?

Comment: FWIW You could `.empty().append('<option value=""></option>');`

Comment: _A thousand_ option elements??

Comment: In the worst case it does contain a very long series of serial number. Maybe it will be changed to an autocompleter in the future but it has to be a simple select for now.

Comment: tested; empty() does not give any significant performarce enhancement over remove()